# Iterating through all lines with multiple conditions

Tags: python, loops, split, line

I want to iterate over all lines at once and check if the string is in any of the lines, if it is then apply a function and break out of the loop, if not then check for the second string and do the same thing. If neither string if found in any of the lines then carry on with the else..

```
split= text.as_string().splitlines()
for row in split:
   if 'Thanks Friend' in row.any():
     apply_some_function()
     break
   elif 'other text' in row.str.any():
     apply_some_function()
     break
   else:
     .......
```

I keep getting the error:

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
      <ipython-input-179-8f0e09f62771> in <module>()
      1 for row in split:
      2 
----> 3   if 'Thanks Friend' in row.str.any():
      4     apply_some_function()
      5     break

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: how to do it, the code above isn't working, keep getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Well, I guess you are from Java background. In Python, you can do things simpler. This is just: `if 'Thanks Friend' in row: ` and `elif 'other text' in row: `, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I want to iterate through all rows at once for each condition, not one at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. But keep in mind that the text will be split at the carriage return which might not be what you want to do. Also, do you want to do something different if 'other text' is in split?  If you do then you need to tell us.

```
split = text.split("\n")
if any(x for x in split if 'Thanks Friend' in x):
    apply_some_function()
elif any(x for x in split if 'other text' in x):
    apply_some_function()
else:
    pass
```

You can also do:

```
if any(x for x in split if 'Thanks Friend' in x) or \:
any(x for x in split if 'other text' in x):
    apply_some_function()
```

Comment: split is already a list, and no I want the same function to be applied if other text is in split, if any of the first two conditions are met, i want to break out of the loop, i.e want the whole iteration to end.

Comment: this works but it keeps running even after the condition is met, is there a way to break out of the loop the first time it returns as true?

Comment: There is no loop in the above code so I don't see how it keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

You are using attributes / methods of objects, that do not exist in python. That is what `AttributeError` means.

One way to find all existing attributes of a object is, to use the function `help()` in the python-console. For example type `help(str)` to get all methods that can be used on strings.

I don't think there is a way to go to all lines "at once" when you want to do different things on each line. So you have to stay with your original code. Here is a fixed version of it:

```
split = text.splitlines()
for row in split:
    if 'Thanks Friend' in row:
        apply_some_function()
        break
    elif 'other text' in row:
        apply_some_function()
     break
   else:
       ...
```